# HashMap vs EnumMap scenario

Tags: java

I am in a dilemma between 2 ways of implementing something and wondered what is more efficient (memory and\or time wise).

I need to get requests containing an *Op-code* and map it to a *Category*. There are between 1000 to 2000 Op-codes only 3-4 categories.
The mapping is predefined and well known.

Solution 1:
using `HashMap<Integer, Category>` 
It's simple but I think it's wasting too much memory because its many to few mapping.

Solution 2:
Predefine an Enumartion:

```
public enum CategoryEum{
C1("123", "456",....),
C2("777","888",...) 
... }
```

And then using this enum for a:

```
EnumMap<CategoryEnum, Category>
```

I read that EnumMap is compact and efficient.

Important note: The Maps in both solutions are initiated once and doesn't change throughout the process life.

What do you think?

Comment: In what range are these op codes? Are they consecutive integers from 0-2000?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I would appreciate an answer referring to this case and the other case

Comment: Are you considering hard-coding the op-code--category mapping in a Java source file, or could you have the data stored in a database?

Comment: Where are the op-code--category mappings currently located -- are they in a file of some sort or just written on paper? What I'm trying to imply is that if the information is in electronic format, you should really consider  importing it to a database (or even a property file), because hard-coding 2000 values seems like a bad idea (in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Consecutive op codes

If your op-codes are consecutive integers between 0 and 2000, you don't need a map. Use the op-codes as indexes of an array, like so (do note that the hard-coding is for sake of example brevity only):

```
Category[] mapping = {
    Category.A, // Opcode 0
    Category.A, // Opcode 1
    Category.B, // Opcode 2
    ...
};

int opcode = ...
Category category = mapping[opcode];
```

#### Sparse op codes

If your op-codes are not consecutive and sparse (with large gaps), your enum solution might work as you could encode the op-codes as enum and use the enum ordinal for the array index:

```
Category[] mapping = {
    Category.A, // Opcode 13 (the first possible opcode)
    Category.A, // Opcode 42 (the second possible opcode)
    Category.B, // Opcode 88 (the third possible opcode)
    ...
};

int opcode = opcodeEnum.ordinal();
Category category = mapping[opcode];
```

Note that in the latter case, `EnumMap` is pretty much doing the exact same thing as the above solution although using up more memory, as it contains some caches for `Map.entrySet()` and other calls.

#### When to prefer the above over `HashMap`

In any case, the array or `EnumMap` solutions should be preferred over the `HashMap` solution if you will provide a category for *every* op code in the possible op code space. If you only categorise 1% of your op codes, then creating the array for the entire op code space will be wasting too much memory, and a `HashMap` might be better.

Comment: Regarding your second solution with Category[], you mean that every cell in the array will hold a pointer for the pertinent Category reference?

Comment: I updated the answer. The opcodes don't correspond to the array indexes, but the opcodes' ordinal within the enum definition (the order of definition) does, if you enumerate opcodes strictly ascendingly.

Comment: Do you really think this is a readable and maintainable solution when the array could have 2000 hard-coded values and for each of these the index would need to be manually marked as a comment?

Comment: Thank you for the straw-man argument. My honest intention was to point out that the solution you've provided to the OP's problem is not sustainable because you've made the mapping implicit instead of explicit, which is really _is_ a problem when you have 2000 op-codes. How will the maintenance programmer check the category of op-code 1234 by looking at the code?

Answer (score 1):

> Solution 1: using `HashMap<Integer, Category>` It's simple but I think it's wasting too much memory because its many to few mapping.

Actually, it's probably no more than 10-20KB which is barely a crumb these days. The `HashMap` is just an array of pointers.

However, if you're converting `int` to `Integer` all the time, that's probably not the best thing in the world.

> `EnumMap<CategoryEnum, Category>`

I don't think this actually helps you out, because now you need to map opcodes to `CategoryEnum`.

If the numerical values of the opcodes aren't very large (a few thousand), then by far the best option is just to use a `Category[]` and index the opcodes in to the array directly. The length of the array needs to be the value of the highest opcode +1.

If the numerical values are more than a few thousand, then it isn't *that* difficult to program your own simple hashtable, just for retrievals. (DIY is kind of like Java heresy, but until they give us primitive generics we are stuck.)

There are some libraries out there with primitive collections as well.

Comment: Regarding your second solution with Category[], you mean that every cell in the array will hold a pointer for the pertinent Category reference?

Comment: Yes, so that you just do `Category cat = table[opcode];`.